# Let $γ$ be sum of two line segments connecting $-2$ with $iy$ and $iy$ with $2$, where $y$ is fixed parameter. Write explicit parametrization for $γ$.

Tags: integration, complex-integration, parametrization, line-integrals, cauchy-integral-formula

**QUESTION**

Let $\gamma$ be the sum of two line segments connecting $-2$ with $iy$ and $iy$ with $2$, where $y$ is a fixed parameter.

**i.** Write an explicit parametrization for $\gamma$.

**ii.** For every $y$, evaluate the integrals $\int_\gamma z dz$ and $\int_\gamma \bar{z} dz$. Which of the integrals is independent of $y$?

**iii.** Use **ii.** to show that the conclusion of Cauchy's theorem does not hold for $f(z)=\bar z$

---

**DOUBT**

I am confused with $y$ parameter and the one in $z=x+iy$. I know how to perform line integrals. But I am not sure how to compute parts **i.** and **ii.** I know the **iii.** part, as the contour is not closed, thus the answer won't be $\color{Tomato}{\text{zero}}$.

I will appreciate any help.

---

**MY TRY**
I guess the line integral from $-2$ to $iy$ and then $iy$ to $2$ becomes $\color{Tomato}{\text{zero}}$, using Cauchy Theorem minus the integral on the line segment $-2$ to $2$? Am I right?

---

Comment: You are right: the contour is not closed. But you can close it adding the segment $[-2,2]$. Note that both integrals on that segment are zero.

Comment: $y$ parameter here is just some real number. If it makes it easier, call it $r$.

Comment: okay thanks ... let me try this way ... by joining ... -2 to 2 on real axis

Comment: @Crostul, i guess the line integral from - 2 to iy and then iy to 2 becomes zero..  using cauchy theorem minus the integral on the line segment -2 to 2 ?? am i right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

An easy and pretty useful (many times) parametrization of the straight line from point $\;(a,b)\,\,\,\text{ to point}\;\;(c,d)\;$ in the plane (real or complex) is

$$\gamma(t) = t(c,d)+(1-t)(a,b)=(\,(1-t)a+tc\,,\,\,(1-t)b+td\,)\;,\;\;\;t\in[0,1]$$

Now, for example: with the second line segment, from $\;(0,y)\;$ to $\;(2,0)\;$ we have:

$$\int_{\gamma_2}\overline z\,dz=\int_0^1\left[\left(1-t)\cdot2+2\cdot0\,,\,(1-t)y+t\cdot0\right)\bullet(2,\,-y)\right]\,dt=$$

$$=\int_0^1\left(4(1-t)-(1-t)y^2\right)\,dt=\ldots$$

As for part (iii): that's either a mistake in the question or, perhaps, they want you to join $\;-2\to2\;$ on the real line and close the two line segments and check there for each of $\;z,\,\overline z\;$

Comment: thanks so much.... :) i understand completey.. i tried to vote...as my reputation is less it didnt work

Comment: i guess you can also help me with this question ... one posted the answer but he is not sure can u review only. ? i will be  highly obliged. 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3239575/finding-complex-function-1-unsure-answer/3239820#3239820